# Automatically controlling an app on the PC using openCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, web-applications, automation

I am working on a project to control the PC exclusively by voice control and gestures(via webcam). So, with the voice control I open the app(for example, YouTube). Now, without typing anything on the search bar, I want to do it through voice typing (without even touching the keyboard), like if I say "search water videos" the cursor will automatically search the thing for me, and give me the result.
Basically, I want to find a text box on a screen of an app using image processing.
There shall be some predefined keywords like, search(for searching), delete(for deleting anything that is mistyped) Go Back(to go back to the previous window), Exit(for exiting the app).

Can it be done with the help of openCV Python?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you want to use voice commands then you can try Speech Recognition using Google Speech API. Why would one use OpenCV for that?

Comment: All I want is to detect a text box on a screen using image processing.